# how do you transfer a Revit property into openmodelica?

Tags: modelica, revit, openmodelica, bim

Does anyone now how to transfer a property in Revit into OpenModelica?
Lets say in Revit there exist a heat pump with a capacity of 2500 Kwh. I would like to use that 2500 in a modelica script.

thank you guys already

Comment: There is no enduser ready GUI tool or script for this, but you can of course save your Revit model to a file, e.g. an IFC file or whatever Revit supports, then write e.g. a Python scripts that reads some values from the file and changes some values in your Modelica model. There might be some interesting publications in this list: http://www.iea-annex60.org/pubs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to access properties in a Revit model. Do you have Revit installed and a session up and running? If so, implement an add-in to access the data. Look at the discussion of [FireRatingCloud](https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud) for a bunch of ideas. The [RvtMetaProp sample](https://github.com/jeremytammik/rvtmetaprop) also showing how to access and export Revit properties.